# How to find an address network?

Tags: addresses, network

I am trying to create a UI to send and receive multiple cryptocurrencies (BTC, ETH, USDT, USDC,...) in different networks (Bitcoin, Ethereum, ERC20, BEP20, TRC20,...).
How can I check whether an address is compatible with selected network, in order to prevent users coin to be sent in wrong addresses in a network which lock the coin forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at these crypto address validators to check whether an address is compatible with a selected network. They are simple wallet address validators for validating Bitcoin and other altcoin addresses in Node.js and browser:

https://github.com/Swyftx/crypto-address-validator

https://github.com/christsim/multicoin-address-validator

Or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multicoin-address-validator

Answer (score 1):

You could either check if

- there is a code at this specific address on the network
- the contract at this address is `ERC20` compliant
- the contract at this address has the correct `name()` and `symbol()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you explain more about solution 2 and 3? is number 1 enough to do that? can this method work for newly generated adderesses? I mean addresses with no transaction.

Comment: Option 1 is probably enough. To understand more about the other two, I suggest you to read the EIP-20: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20
Can you clarify with your second concern please ?

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I mean perhaps there's no record about an address on blockchain but it is still valid for that network, like a newly generated address.